# parsing a large html-file (local) - with Perl or PHP

Tags: php, perl, text-parsing

I have a large document - I need to parse it and spit out only this part: schule.php?schulnr=80287&lschb=

how do I parse the stuff!?

```
<td>
    <A HREF="schule.php?schulnr=80287&lschb=" target="_blank">
        <center><img border=0 height=16 width=15 src="sh_info.gif"></center>
    </A>
</td>
```

Love to hear from you

Comment: Use a regular expression and bow to the dark lord. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: I was about to say "what kind of a dolt posts a blog post about how to do this Bad Thing... then I noticed it was Coding Horror :) [ for the un-initiated, Coding Horror blog owner is one of the 2 co-founders of StackOverflow and definitely a better programmer than myself :) ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do it this way (it's not perl but more "visual"):

- Load the document into your browser,
  if possible
- Install Firebug extension/add-on
- Install FirePath extension
- Copy + Paste this XPath expression
  into the text field labeled "XPpath:"

  //a[contains(@href, "schule")]/@href
- Click "Eval" button.

There are also tools to do this on the command line, e.g. "xmllint" (for unix)

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//a[contains(@href, "schule")]/@href' myfile.php.or.html
```

You could do further processing from thereon.

Answer (score 5):

You ought to use a DOM parser like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: hi Rfygyhn - many thanks. I will do this!  I come back and let you know what i have experienced. best regards

Answer (score 5):

In Perl, the quickest and best way, I know to scan HTML is [`HTML::PullParser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::PullParser). This is based on a robust HTML parser, not simple FSA like Perl regex (without recursion).

This is more like a SAX filter, than a  DOM.

```
use 5.010;
use constant NOT_FOUND => -1;
use strict;
use warnings;

use English qw<$OS_ERROR>;
use HTML::PullParser ();

my $pp 
    = HTML::PullParser->new(
      # your file or even a handle
      file        => 'my.html'
      # specifies that you want a tuple of tagname, attribute hash
    , start       => 'tag, attr' 
      # you only want to look at tags with tagname = 'a'
    , report_tags => [ 'a' ],
    ) 
    or die "$OS_ERROR"
    ;

my $anchor_url;
while ( defined( my $t = $pp->get_token )) { 
    next unless ref $t or $t->[0] ne 'a'; # this shouldn't happen, really
    my $href = $t->[1]->{href};
    if ( index( $href, 'schule.php?' ) > NOT_FOUND ) { 
        $anchor_url = $href;
        last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What Rfvgyhn said, but in Perl flavor since that was one of the tags: use [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~jfearn/HTML-Tree-4.1/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm)

Plus, for reasons as to why RegEx is **almost** never a good idea to parse XML/HTML (sometimes it's Good Enough With Major Caveats), read the obligatory and infamous StackOverflow post:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Mind you, if the full extent of your task is literally "parse out HREF links", AND you don't have "<link>" tags AND the links (e.g. `HREF="something"` substrings) are guaranteed not to be used in any other context (e.g. in comments, or as text, or have "HREF=" be part of the link itself), it just might fall into the "Good Enough" category above for regex usage:

```
my @lines = <>; # Replace with proper method of reading in your file
my @hrefs = map { $_ =~ /href="([^"]+)"/gi; } @lines;
```